# What's a less profane alternative to "as f**k"?

Tags: phrase-requests

*As fuck* is a common way to end sentences in slang language — for example, "I'm drunk as fuck." What is the formal (appropriate) equivalent phrase that gives the exact same meaning and sounds just as befitting?

I do apologize if this question seems bang out of line or impertinent. My intentions are totally pure and it's just that the question has been lingering in my head for some time... plus, I want to quit using it and start using a more appropriate decent phrase.

Note: I'm not after adverbs such as *very, extremely* etc... I'm looking for a phrase.

Comment: *Drunk as fuck* is essentially a more colourful way of saying *too drunk* or *very drunk*. If, however, you truly don't want that kind of adverb, then I recommend *as drunk as can be* or *as drunk as possible*.

Comment: It doesn't "end sentences"... it is part of the sentence.

Comment: Very surprised nobody has mentioned ***drunk as a skunk***.

Comment: Fuck, if other formations were as juicy, we'd use **them**.

Answer (score 7):

I'm XXX **as all get out** is common.
[Websters](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20get-out):

> the utmost conceivable degree —used in comparisons to suggest something superlative

See also this stack question: [Origin of “as all get out” meaning “to the utmost degree”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190420/origin-of-as-all-get-out-meaning-to-the-utmost-degree)

Comment: "XXX as sin" is another popular (and succinct) formulation.

Comment: "XXX as all get out" would not be as widely understood as "XXX as f**k"

Comment: Sorry for the down-vote. Google ngrams suggests I'm wrong if we assume prevalence in printed matter is correlated with intelligibility. I will up-vote if stackexchange lets me. I still think I'm right but without evidence to prove it my down-vote is unjust.

Comment: @mikeyreilly Huh, it's making a comeback. I figured you had to be old to know the phrase.

Answer (score 6):

The term "drunk as fuck", as you mentioned, uses "as fuck" as an intensifier — in this case a particularly vulgar one.

You mentioned you wanted a phrase. The phrase "as fuck" mimics a simile, using "fuck" as a word representing a generic, intense object. If you want a less profane term, you could invent a simile of your own. Here are a few examples to give you some ideas, with varying levels of appropriateness:

> I'm as drunk as **a Russian at a strip club.**
>
> I'm as drunk as **a frat boy during initiation.**
>
> I'm **exactly as think as you drunk I am.**
>
> I'm as drunk as **[Quagmire from *Family Guy*](http://www.adultswim.com/videos/family-guy/i-never/) in a [*Never Have I Ever*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Never_Have_I_Ever) game.**
>
> I'm as drunk as [**a wood spider that had rubbing alcohol swabbed on its back.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHzdsFiBbFc)

It's a fun exercise in general. Try coming up with a few of your own.

Answer (score 5):

...as hell might work and be slightly less NC17

Answer (score 4):

A one-size-fits-all simile is "**as can be**", meaning "*to as great an extent as is possible.*"

**I'm as drunk as can be** (although in my opinion, you shouldn't be able to speak at that point).

**I'm as full as can be**

**She's as cute as can be**

Answer (score -1):

"**Drunk as a lord**" still seems  a modern phrase, although it's not as popular as the  recently introduced "drunk as a skunk": [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drunk+as+a+lord%2Cdrunk+as+a+skunk&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrunk%20as%20a%20lord%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrunk%20as%20a%20skunk%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdrunk%20as%20a%20lord%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrunk%20as%20a%20skunk%3B%2Cc0).