# What is a better, less vulgar phrase than "take s**t from"?

Tags: phrase-requests, offensive-language

I'm looking for something better than "take shit".  For example, "The clerk refused to take shit from the enraged customer."  Specifically, I'm looking for something less vulgar.  I looked at the question [as f**k](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205970/whats-a-less-profane-alternative-to-as-fk), but this is not quite the same, as "shit" is not being used as an intensifier. I thought about using the word "abuse", but that seems more intentional vs. the more random or spontaneous behavior that I tried to convey in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't take [**guff**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guff) or [**backtalk**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/back%20talk) from customers.

They both mean disrespect — or comments that are *impudent, insolent, or argumentative*. Rude, completely unwelcome. Instead, I've said:

> "Oh, I don't seem to be able to help you. Let me get someone who can." *The subtext is I don't take shit from anyone*.

Customer Service sometimes has success in de-escalating calls by showing empathy through validation:

> "Yes, I can tell by your voice that you're upset. That I understand. Will you let me help you?" *The subtext is I don't take shit from anyone*.

Comment: Perfect.  That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: It may be perfect in American usage but would not be well understood in Britain, where people would not “put up with” it.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Backtalk is AE, and [Back talk](https://www.lexico.com/definition/back_talk) is UK Oxford Lexico. Cheeky?

Comment: Note that, in the US, 'guff' sounds -very- old-fashioned. Like 'malarky'.

Comment: True, that's why I'd say *Sorry, I don't get paid enough to take that!*

Answer (score 2):

How about **would not stand any nonsense**?

Comment: SNow, although I must admit to have disapproved of some of your contributions to this list, I applaud you for an answer that is clear, straightforward English. To your rhetorical question — Yes indeed!